# Detect TLS Version in Node Express App?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ssl

Is it possible to detect the TLS version 1.1 or 1.2 etc in Node Express application.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tlssocket_getprotocol

Answer (score 4):

If your are using `express` you can try with:

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.protocol === 'https')
    console.log(req.connection.getProtocol());
  else
    console.log('Not SSL');
});
```